# Name of Class <T> of a generic Class

Tags: java, generics

I have a small problem in java while using generics. I have a class A :

```
public class A<T>
```

In a method of A, I need to get the type name of T. Is there a way to find the string s using T ?

(If I create `A<String> temp = new A<String>();`, I want to be able to get java.lang.String at one point - I have to use generics because one of my methods will have to return a List).

This seems quite easy but I do not see how to do it.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), this is not possible.

Instead, you need to accept a `Type<T>` in your constructor.

Comment: Wow. I was *just* coding somethng with the same requirement. Got [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2886414/programmatically-implementing-an-interface-that-combines-some-instances-of-the-s) which uses knowledge of a field in the class.

Comment: (If I create A<String> temp = new A<String>();, I want to be able to get java.lang.String

Comment: @yassiro: I know.  However, that's not possible.  Instead, you need to write `A<String> temp = new A<String>(String.class);`

Comment: do tou try it !!
System.out.println(x.getClass().getName());
 it gives me the name of the generic class "A"

Comment: @yassiro: Correct.  You need to check the `Type` instance that was passed as a parameter.

Comment: You don't know how to use a constructor parameter? You need to learn Java.

Comment: You need to print the value of the constructor parameter.

Comment: i cant understand you!! plz give me an exemple

Comment: **i want to have a dynamic Jtable (this JTable can display many different Object "person","Student" )so i create a genereic TableModel then i want a name of the class T to get the fields of the class T!!!
 this my vision if someone need the code to understand what i mean, i"ll send it to him***

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, because generics are implemented using "erasure": there's actually just a single `A` class internally, and the `<String>` gets "erased" before run-time. The best solution, in my experience, is to add a private final field, `Class<T> tClass`, and to require it to be specified in the constructor:

```
public A(final Class<T> tClass)
{
    this.tClass = tClass;
}
```

You would then have to write

```
A<String> temp = new A<String>(String.class);
```

instead of just

```
A<String> temp = new A<String>();
```

Comment: (If I create A<String> temp = new A<String>();, I want to be able to get java.lang.String

Comment: @yassiro: Yes, I understand that. Unfortunately, you force me to quote the Rolling Stones: "You can't always get what you want / But if you try sometimes you might find / You get what you need." You *want* `new A<String>()` to somehow record `String` at run-time; but you can't get that. So the question is, how to get what you *need*?

Comment: **i want to have a dynamic Jtable (this JTable can display many different Object "person","Student" )so i create a genereic TableModel then i want a name of the class T to get the fields of the class T!!!
 this my vision if someone need the code to understand what i mean, i"ll send it to him***